# Android observable data objects in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I'm pretty new to data binding stuff so I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about this. I have a `RecyclerView` of `SearchResult` objects I made observable, set up the class like in the docs, extending `BaseObservable`, using `@Bindabl`e on getters and notifying in setters. In the `RecyclerView` item layout, I set the databinding stuff, also according to the docs, code seems correct as in it auto completes to the correct things. Is there something else I need to be doing to make it work? It doesn't throw any errors when running, just doesn't bind values to the UI.

In

```
public class SearchResult extends BaseObservable
```

I have

```
@Bindable
String getTitle() { return this.title; }

void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title);
}
```

and in the `TextView` of the `RecyclerView` item layout I have

```
android:text="@{searchresult.title}"
```

Is there something else I need to be doing to get this to bind data to `RecyclerView` items? Perhaps something in the `RecyclerView` adapter, or maybe a completely different way to go about binding each instance of an object to an item in the `RecyclerView`?